# Does any shastra mentions wheat or bajra?

Tags: scripture

I heard that wheat and bajra came very late in India while many other crops were there much before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wheat is godhuma in Sanskrit and in some dialects of punjabbi is still called gandam.

It is mentioned along with masur in the Rudram chamakam.

Bajra called priyangu or priyanga in sanskrit, it's two lines above in the same verse.
[image]